# Why is my appended form data not making it to the controller on submit?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

On submit of form2 I am attaching data from form1. On submit, jQuery intercepts and does the following:

```
var Submit_frm2 = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $frm2 = (this);
    //get form 1 data
    var $frm1Data = $($("#frm1").serializeArray());
   //get form 2 data
    var frm2Data = $("#frm2").serializeArray();

    //  add form 1 data to form 2 data
    $frm1Data.each(function (i, e) {
       frm2Data.push({ name: "frmOneData." + e.name, value: e.value });
    });

     this.submit();
};
```

simplified class example of form 2

```
public partial class FormTwoData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string someString { get; set; }
    public List<SomeType> listOfTypes { get; set; }
    public FormOneData frmOneData
}
```

simplified class example of form 1

```
public partial class FormOneData
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string someString { get; set; }
    public string anotherString { get; set; }
}
```

A break point at this.submit() shows that form1's data has been added, but the frmTwoData class is null when it reaches the Controller.

I have spent hours googling to no avail, and none of my colleagues have ever done anything like this. I am totally stumped.

I hope that I have added enough information.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer.

Comment: You are submitting to an action method which has `FormTwoData` as the parameter ? normal form submission is going to read the form body input values, not your javascript variable value.

Comment: I got the idea from a stack answer where they were adding just a couple items manually.

Comment: The variable `frm2Data`is just a variable, its data is not the data from the form that you are submitting

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that i wasn't doing anything with that after adding data.